# How to debug an app activated from dock menu

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to understand how to debug a dock open document event.

I'd like to understand the environment so that normal document restoration can be disabled on startup when the app is stated to open some document, especially when the doc itself is a candidate for restoration.

But, since the app is seemingly started, "no debug", breaks in several app delegate methods are never called; i.e.,

- func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool
- func applicationDockMenu(sender: NSApplication) -> NSMenu?

As each document open event will instantiate a document window, normally I'd like to avoid that but having so is useful, so I'd like the ability to debug it while in this sort of start up, so long as I'm attached to the debugger.

Comment: If you are launching the app from the Dock, you are not launching it from the Xcode debugger

Comment: Yes I realize the doc is launching the app, but it's the same built debug app itself I had dragged onto the dock. I'm going about this wrongly which is my question.

Comment: Just because it’s a debug build doesn’t mean it’s attached to the debugger. You can manually attach it to a debugger after it has been started or use `os_log` statements so that you can monitor an app from the Console when not attached to a debugger (see [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59145084/1271826)).

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is not possible - to have the launch be the debugger, but as a concession would be to know if the app was started via a doc menu item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug the app launch process while the app is not connected to a debugger, you may need to just rely on [unified logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging). For example, I often use this pattern, with a private `OSLog` for each source file, which I can then observe these log statements in the Console:

```
//  ViewController.swift

import Cocoa
import os.log

private let log = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "ViewController")

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var string = "..."

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        os_log(.debug, log: log, "viewDidLoad: string = %{public}@", string)
    }

    ...    
}
```

Then, if the Console is configured to show debugging statements (e.g. “Action” » “Include Debug Messages”), I can filter for these (e.g. type `subsystem:` in the search bar, followed by your subsystem, the bundle identifier in this case). Then, completely independent of Xcode, I can watch these log statements from the Console app (and filter for my subsystem and/or category) as my app runs, not attached to the debugger:

[image]

This technique works for both macOS and iOS apps.

For more information, see the [Unified Logging and Activity Tracing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/) video.

---

Obviously, once your debug build is running, but having been launched independently of the debugger, you can manually attach Xcode’s debugger to it via the “Debug” » “Attach to process” menu option.

[image]

But attaching a debugger to an app that is already running is not practical when you’re trying to debug the startup sequence when an app launches. But the aforementioned unified logging is often sufficient for confirming what methods were called when, through the judicious use of `os_log` statements.